# Is this an alternative to the Pythagoras theorem or a Proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, solution-verification

$\triangle$ABC, BC = 3 AC = 4

$\triangle$DEF, EF = 3

($\triangle$DEF can be created by using one of the given sides in $\triangle$ABC
and angles of $\triangle$DEF will be the same as $\triangle$ABC where both C and F are right angles.)

(We are Finding AB),

Step 1: Find DF using the ratio of $\angle$E where $\angle$E = $\angle$A.

Ratio of $\angle$E = DF/3

Ratio of $\angle$A = 3/4

DF/3 = 3/4

DF = 9/4

Step 2: Prove that $\triangle$ABC $\sim$ $\triangle$DEF by AA-

$\angle$A =  $\angle$E

$\angle$C = $\angle$F

Therefore: $\triangle$ABC $\sim$ $\triangle$DEF by AA-

Step 3: Find DE using the scaled factor.

DE = AB(3/4)

step 4: Reflect $\triangle$DEF in the x-axis and align BC and DF to get $\triangle$ABD

Diagram of [$\triangle$ ABD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B49fX.png)

(BC)(AD)/2 = A, Equation 1
(BD)(AB)/2 = A, Equation 2

(A represents the area of $\triangle$ABD)

Substitute 1 into 2

(BC)(AD) = (BD)(AB), Equation 3

(AD = AC + DF)

Substitute AB, BC, AC ,DE and DF into 3

3(4 + 9/4) = (AB$^2$)3/4

3(25/4) = (AB$^2$)3/4

(25)3/4 = (AB$^2$)3/4

AB$^2$ = 25

AB = 5

Comment: If I assume the title of your question is what you intended to ask, the body of the question seems irrelevant. Please rewrite to formulate a question in the body (one that matches the title) and explain what you are doing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to ask.

 Does ^ mean triangle? (use $\$\backslash$triangle\$).

 Does < mean angle? (use $\$\backslash$angle\$) 

Please look up Mathjax [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) or [here](https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols). Then edit your post for better effect and fewer downvotes.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, I have fixed the formatting and I hope that it is more understandable now, thanks for the feedback, this is my first time using this site so I am not familiar with how it works yet.

Comment: I think your proof  is very close to [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Proof_using_similar_triangles).

Comment: Sorry but which one are you referring to? The link just leads to many different ones.

Comment: "Proof using similar triangles". It's not exactly the same, but the general setup and the idea of using ratios of sides to get the relation is very similar.

Comment: Anyway, your idea is correct, and is essentially the Pythagorean theorem. It could be stated in more general form (that is, without specific numbers).

Comment: But even using the general form I'm not sure how it can be proven that it is equivalent to the Pythagorean theorem

Comment: I noticed that your post was closed. If you are still interested in attracting new answers, you should edit your post to try to get it reopened. Some suggestions: you never state that $C$ is a right angle. You never say how  to construct triangle $DEF$ except for stating that it uses one of the sides of $ABC$. In particular, you don't say anything about its angles. If you have a diagram, can you add it to the post? It seems to me, however, that you could just start  with the triangle $ABD$ that you ultimately end up with instead of starting with two separate triangles and then joining them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a triangle $ABD$ with right angle at $B$ and a line through $B$ perpendicular to $\overline{AD}$ at $C$.

Your equation
$$
3\cdot\left(4+\frac{9}{4}\right)=(AB)^2\cdot\frac{3}{4}
$$
could be generalized to
$$
(BC)\cdot\left(AC+\frac{(BC)^2}{(AC)}\right)=(AB)^2\cdot\frac{BC}{AC}.
$$
If you multiply both sides by $(AC)$ and divide both sides by $(BC)$ you get
$$
(AC)^2+(BC)^2=(AB)^2,
$$
which is the Pythagorean theorem.